# Obtain a full list of valid system_info atoms

Tags: erlang, environment-variables, system, introspection

I've guessed a couple of the `erlang:system_info/1` variants such as:

```
10> erlang:system_info(schedulers).
4
11> erlang:system_info(cpu).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  erlang:system_info/1
        called as erlang:system_info(cpu)

12> erlang:system_info(cpu_arch).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  erlang:system_info/1
        called as erlang:system_info(cpu_arch)

13> erlang:system_info(memory).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  erlang:system_info/1
        called as erlang:system_info(memory)

14> erlang:system_info(version).
"5.10.4"
```

But is there a way, either via introspection, or a global database of some sort, to list all the available system_info arguments ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the documentation for [`erlang:system_info/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#system_info-1). It's listed over several sections with descriptions for what each atom represents. This is the most comprehensive list of supported atoms outside of the Erlang/OTP source itself (and there are a few undocumented parameters).

There is no language feature which would allow you to list all of the possible atoms.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the info, and clarification about programmatic iteration.